# How do I make my discord bot react with an emoji

Tags: python, discord.py

I have tried every goddamn thing, I cant get this to work. I want the bot to react with a checkmark to the embed when I write the command, but with everything that I've tried I get this string error. I have now tried for 2 hours with no luck. Please help me. I am using discord.py.

```
@client.command()
async def verification(ctx):
    
    verifyEmbed = discord.Embed(
        title="VERIFY",
        description="To get access to the server you need to verify. \nVerify by reacting with :white_check_mark: \n\n ",
        color=discord.Colour.green()
    )

    embedMsg = await ctx.send(embed=verifyEmbed)
    checkM = client.get_emoji("✅")
    await embedMsg.add_reaction(checkM)
```

Error message:

```
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: InvalidArgument: emoji argument must be str, Emoji, or Reaction not NoneType.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full text of the error or traceback you're getting.

Comment: @MattDMo I have edited it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[get_emoji](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_emoji#discord.Client.get_emoji) is for getting an emoji by ID, so it is returning `None` and that is causing your error in `add_reaction`

You could just put the check emoji straight into add_reaction, but I recommend adding the reaction by unicode representation:

```
await embedMsg.add_reaction('\N{WHITE HEAVY CHECK MARK}')
```